# Parse multi line JSON in R

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I have a JSON input which I am getting from a server, I want to parse this into a data frame object.

Structure:

Compact Form

```
'{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[{"id":"1","key":["1001"],"value":{"context":"1001","application_id":"1","cust_assets_total":1550000}},{"id":"2","key":["1001"],"value":{"context":"1001","application_id":"2","cust_assets_total":1550000}}]}'
```

Pretty Form

```
{
  "total_rows": 2,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "key": [
        "1001"
      ],
      "value": {
        "context": "1001",
        "application_id": "1",
        "cust_assets_total": 1550000
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "key": [
        "1001"
      ],
      "value": {
        "context": "1001",
        "application_id": "2",
        "cust_assets_total": 1550000
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
context application_id cust_assets_total
1001    1              1550000
1001    2              1550000
```

**Code Used:**

```
library(jsonlite)

raw_data <- '{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[{"id":"1","key":["1001"],"value":{"context":"1001","application_id":"1","cust_assets_total":1550000}},{"id":"2","key":["1001"],"value":{"context":"1001","application_id":"2","cust_assets_total":1550000}}]}'

temp <-fromJSON(paste(readLines(raw_data),collapse=""))
```

But this resulted in error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[{"id":"1","key":["1001"],"value":{"context":"1001","application_id":"1","cust_assets_total":1550000}},{"id":"2","key":["1001"],"value":{"context":"1001","application_id":"2","cust_assets_total":1550000}}]}': No such file or directory
```

Comment: If `raw_data` is already in R, why not just `fromJSON(raw_data)`?  As for the error, I believe you may be missing `textConnection`, as in `readLines(textConnection(raw_data))`

Comment: raw_data would be the downloaded from a web using Rcurl, that is raw_data <- getURL(url), will check what you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could readLines if you wrapped `textConnection` around "raw_data" but it's much easier to leave it out:

```
> temp <-fromJSON(raw_data)
> temp
$total_rows
[1] 2

$offset
[1] 0

$rows
  id  key value.context value.application_id value.cust_assets_total
1  1 1001          1001                    1                 1550000
2  2 1001          1001                    2                 1550000
```

Note:... this version of `fromJSON` gives you a three-element named list.

Comment: Feel dumb asking the question now, Thanks for the solution